# Spring Boot Mongo Data - How to Set Naming Strategy

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently working on a Spring Boot project where the variable names are written in camel case. I also have a MongoDB database with fields written in snake case. Currently I am using @Field annotation provided by Spring Mongo Data to map each variable to its corresponding logical name like this:

```
@Field("var_name")
private String varName;
```

My question is - Is there a way to configure globally an automatic Camel Case to Snake Case conversion in Spring Mongo Data? If I have a model with many instance variables, it would be trivial to add a @Field annotation for each of them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` in `application.properties`

Comment: @varman Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I had already added that line to my application.properties.  However I believe that only converts camel case to snake case in JSON responses returned from controller. Objects initialized from db query still fail to map to the correct fields in the db.

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Boot, you can add "field-naming-strategy" into your application.yml like this:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      username: xxxxx
      password: yyyyy
      authentication-database: admin
      database: my_mongo_db
      field-naming-strategy: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this at global level:

1. To override MongoMappingContext:

```
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

  @Override
  public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(uri);
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext(MongoCustomConversions customConversions) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
    mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(this.getInitialEntitySet());
    mappingContext.setSimpleTypeHolder(customConversions.getSimpleTypeHolder());
    mappingContext.setFieldNamingStrategy(new SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy()); //NOTE this line
    mappingContext.setAutoIndexCreation(this.autoIndexCreation());
    return mappingContext;
  }
```

Here we override the mappingContext and pass snakeCasing, default for which is camel.

2. To update codecRegistry

```
public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(
        MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(uri))
            .codecRegistry(codecRegistry())
            .build());
  }
  public CodecRegistry codecRegistry() {
    List<Convention> conventions = Collections.<Convention>singletonList(
        classModelBuilder -> {
          for (PropertyModelBuilder<?> fieldModelBuilder : classModelBuilder.getPropertyModelBuilders()) {
            fieldModelBuilder.discriminatorEnabled(false);
            fieldModelBuilder.readName(
                fieldModelBuilder.getName()
                    .replaceAll("([^_A-Z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").toLowerCase());
            fieldModelBuilder.writeName(
                fieldModelBuilder.getName()
                    .replaceAll("([^_A-Z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").toLowerCase());
          }

          classModelBuilder.enableDiscriminator(true);
          classModelBuilder.discriminatorKey("_cls");
          classModelBuilder.discriminator(classModelBuilder.getType().getSimpleName()
              .replaceAll("([^_A-Z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").toLowerCase());
        });
    CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider =
        PojoCodecProvider.builder().conventions(conventions).build();
    return fromRegistries(getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));
  }
```

The 2nd one is taken from the test mentioned [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/r3.5.0/bson/src/test/unit/org/bson/codecs/pojo/PojoCustomTest.java#L136), and better explanation is [here in the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/data-formats/pojo-customization/#customize-a-pojocodecprovider)
Though I couldnt get 2nd one working but as per [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2615?focusedCommentId=1690311&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1690311) comment it should ideally.

Reference:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/r3.5.0/bson/src/test/unit/org/bson/codecs/pojo/PojoCustomTest.java#L136

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mappingContext.setFieldNamingStrategy(new SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy()) in your Mongo configuration class?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31523783)

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."